# reverse the nesting of elements with python lxml.etree

Tags: python, lxml

I'm looking for a recipe for python's lxml.etree that will reverse the nesting of elements, turning:

```
<text>
    <name>
        <ref>foobar</ref>
    </name>
</text>
```

into:

```
<text>
    <ref>
        <name>foobar</name>
    </ref>
</text>
```

I've a feeling this is obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<ref><name><text>foobar</text></name></ref>`?

Comment: no, I want to search in <text> for all instances of `<ref><name></name></ref>` and reverse their nesting as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
import lxml.etree as et
from lxml.builder import E

xml = """
<text>
    <name>
        <ref>foobar</ref>
    </name>
</text>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xml)

for name in tree.findall('name'):
    text = name.find('ref').text
    tree.replace(name, E.ref(E.name(text)))

print et.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: Why yes. Something very like that. `tree.find('text')` returns None, but altered to `text = tree.getroottree()`, it works a treat. I was hoping there might be a shortcut in etree, but this works fine. Thanks @Acorn

Comment: Oops, fixed. I forgot that when you parse an XML document you begin in the context of the root node.

Comment: Updated to a more compact solution using E-factory.

Comment: I should've read the _rest_ of the tutorial. I didn't know about the E-factory. There's a lot to lxml. This'll save me a lot of time. Thanks so much @Acorn!